# Simple Registry Optimizer for Windows PC

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I am looking for a Registry Optimizer for Windows. It should:
run locally on Windows- be a normal program

Preferable:

- simple and lightweight
- open-source or Paid
- Repairing Registry Errors
- Registry Optimization

Answer (score 3):

According to a well-kmown and respected Windows System Admin (Twitter: @SwiftOnSecurity) Registry Cleaners are at [best useless and usually actually damaging](https://decentsecurity.com/#/registry-cleaners/).

> Windows registry cleaners and optimizers look for banal, often
>   completely fake, things in an immensely intricate system that people
>   are scared of and don't understand. These programs use this position
>   of trust to extort money and mislead users into believing they are
>   required to fix specific problems or improve a flawed system.

And:

> In fact, registry cleaners will invariably find tens, sometimes
>   hundreds or thousands of "issues" on a Windows system installed from a
>   DVD an hour ago. You can test this yourself, it's a well-known way to
>   demonstrate these programs have no idea what they are doing. ”Registry
>   cleaners” will offer to damage a brand-new installation of Windows
>   just to make it look like they are useful. Imagine being told your
>   brand-new car with 50 miles on it needs the “headlight fluid”
>   replaced. It’s the same scam.

I've never been helped by a Registry Cleaner on any version of Windows since 3.1. SwiftOnSecurity might be a bit over the top on this, but not by much.

Comment: "headlight fluid" -- that's hilarious.

Comment: She is very amusing - her twitter feed is hilarious, in many ways.